Rulling on fictional character who has the ability to see the future but said ability is not magical or divine
I know about the fact that if a fictional character having the ability to see the future is prohibited as it is a divine ability belonging to Allah only.But if a fiction has a character that gets the ability to see the future not from magic or divination,but from nuclear fallout/radiation,would it be also considered prohibited?
